# How to modify the user space and kernel space in xv6?

Tags: operating-system, xv6

XV6 has 2 GB for user space and 2 GB for kernel space. If I want to change it to 3 GB for user space and 1 GB for kernel space. How should I implement this modification?
I tried modify KERNBASE + PHYSTOP in memlayout.h and then modify the start address in the linker script kernel.ld. But it failed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to touch `PHYSTOP` to do this, just KERNBASE... For the new start address, did you use `new KERNBASE + 0x100000`? Comment in [kernel.ld](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/kernel.ld#L11) states that the value "[m]ust be equal to KERNLINK".

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not wrong. Are you running xv6 using QEMU? If so, modify the Makefile and increase the memory to 4GB or more.
There are place where memory is set using the -m option around line 215 of the file.　The default is 512 GB.

```
QEMUOPTS = -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp $(CPUS) -m 512 $(QEMUEXTRA)
```

Then modify the memlayout.h and the kernel.ld file.
Probably it should work. If xv6 does not work, please tell me the part that failed. Please also show the modified memlayout.h and kernel.ld file.

Comment: There is no need to change the value supplied to QEMU. The OP's question is about **virtual memory** not **physical memory**. Changing the QEMU `-m` flag changes the "physical" memory available to xV6 (as it runs in the computer emulated by QEMU). Also, `-m 512` specifies 512 megabytes, not 512 gigabytes (see `man qemu`).